# GNU BFD on binary results to "No such file or directory" (binary not executed)

Tags: c, portable-executable, bfd

There is this piece of C code that is used extract info from binaries:

```
bincode_t *initialize_bincode(const char *file)
{
    bfd *abfd;
    bincode_t *bin;
    //char *target = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu";
    char *target = "i686-pc-linux-gnu";

    bfd_init();

    if (!bfd_set_default_target(target)) {
        bs_dbgmsg("  (!) bfd_set_default_target()\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((abfd = bfd_openr(file, target)) == NULL) {
        bs_dbgmsg("  (!) bfd_openr(): %s\n", file);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!bfd_check_format(abfd, bfd_object)) {
        //isolated the error to be here (through simple print debugging)
        bs_dbgmsg("  (!) bfd_check_format()\n");
        printf("Error: %s", bfd_errmsg(bfd_get_error()));
        bfd_close(abfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    if((bin = malloc(sizeof(bincode_t))) == NULL) {
        bs_errmsg("  (!) malloc(): bin\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

I ran this code on Linux against 2 Windows binary samples. However, one of sample results in an error of

> Error: File format not recognized ... Section flag STYP_DSECT (0x1) ignored

The `file` command on both samples results in the following output:

> fc671a044d48bffe519a89b06d289d83f52958cb: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel
>   80386, for MS Windows

and

> fe0c189a5067a2dfe46bad1c2cedaa5b7bbc6a20: PE32 executable (DLL) (GUI)
>   Intel 80386, for MS Windows

The second binary (DLL) results into the error. My question is, why did this happen? What can I do to resolve this? I would like the code to also "see" the DLL binary.

I plugged the DLL binary into gdb and indeed gdb didn't recognize the file. GDB output:

> ...not in executable format: File format not recognised

Edit 1:
Added code and completed error message output. Kindly note that I am a C beginner.

Edit 2:
As suggested in the comments, I have used `bfd_errmsg(bfd_get_error())` and included the output above.

Comment: Show us your code so we can answer your question. From what you've described, it sounds like you're not accessing the file correctly.

Comment: Is it documented that bfd_check_format sets errno?

Comment: on error, bfd_check_format returns false with following error codes: `bfd_error_invalid_operation`, `file_not_recognised`, etc

Comment: I am not sure if `strerror(errno)` was correct or not in showing the error message in the preceding code

Comment: You should print `bfd_errmsg (bfd_get_error ())` instead.

Comment: @TomTromey Thanks for the suggestion that indeed was helpful. The file format was not recognized. Any thoughts on why is this the case and/or how to get around this?

Comment: The thing I'd look at is what targets were configured in BFD.  You could try rebuilding it, configuring with `--enable-targets=all`.